# Category of a component

Tags: delphi, components, categories

I would like to know if it is possible to know the category of a component at run time.
For example, if I have a TLabel it is category is Standard, this means that the component TLabel is in the Standard Tool Palette.

I need that to check if the component is one of my own creations, because I have a lot of new components and I don't want to check with a lots of ifs conditions...

thanks

Comment: If you need to distinguish your components only, you could interpose a class between TComponent and your creations and inherit **all** your components from it (this is a good practice which allows you to introduce some new features for all your component later)

Comment: All of your components should implement an interface (e.g. IMyOwnComponentInformation) to get some information (e.g. build number, revision) or only just for identification purpose

Comment: @pf that won't work. What if you want to derive from TCustomEdit, say, or TGraphicControl, or TCustomListView.

Comment: @David You are right.

Comment: @Felipe, Simply create a prefix for that specific component such as TMyLabel or whatever to identify a component by it's creator therefor yourself. That's standard practice.

Comment: If your own units follow a naming scheme, you can use the TOBject.UnitName function to check if your component is from such a unit.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it will help in my delphi developments.

Answer (score 5):

The category where the component is installed into the tool palette is determined by the call to RegisterComponent, which itself usually is part of a Register procedure. This Register procedure is called from the IDE when it installs a design time package.

In short: there is little hope that you can find out the category at runtime as it is not bound to the component itself. Instead it is more some information for the IDE and thus only handled there.